# phpmailer headers fake address prevention

Tags: php, phpmailer

I want to send some confirmation emails to the users of my site.

Here is how I set up the headers.

```
$headers = "From: ".EMAIL_FROM_NAME." <".EMAIL_FROM_ADDR.">";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
```

I realized that I can set the two constants "EMAIL_FROM_NAME" and "EMAIL_FROM_ADDR"
the way I want. Therefore, I can set the EMAIL_FROM_ADDR even to an address that does not belong to me. And the message will be delivered, right?

So, there is no security at all? What if someone else does the same to me? How can I prevent that?

Thank you

Comment: SMTP was never designed to be a secure protocol. It's always been utterly trivial to forge a "From" address in an email. There may be settings in your SMTP server to not allow 'foreign' From addresses, and receiving SMTP servers may reject the forged mail as Spam, but there's no way to tell for sure until you try.

Comment: You can also forge sender's address in regular mail.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into [Sender Policy Framework (SPF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework).